# HTTPS/SSL on Google Cloud Platform instance

Tags: ssl, https, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I've been tasked to move one domain/subdomains to HTTPS. We already have a Wildcard SSL certificate from RapidSSL, but I'm a bit confused on the overall process.

I can get the Intermediate CA .cer and ssl_certificatie .cer from RapidSSL, but I sort of lose it after that. I see that there is an option on the App Engine for uploading SSL certificates (see screenshot below), but I have no clue what the PEM encoded X.509 public key certificate or Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key are and where to get them.

Does anyone have any guidance?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx4P9.png)

Answer (score 1):

The first field (public key) should contain your ssl certificate (you might also have to include the intermediate). The second one is for the the private key, that one cannot be downloaded from RapidSSL. It was created for the initial SSL certificate request and should be on the server which is currently hosting the site.